# Designing Azure Cloud Logging Framework

Tags: .net, azure, logging, queue, cloud

I am having trouble finding information on standard practices for designing and implementing a resilient logging framework for applications living in the azure cloud. The idea is that the applications don't need to know about or handle logging themselves and the logging of informational\ error messages can be taken care of "in the background"

The design I was considering is basically the "Queue-Based Load Levelling Pattern" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589783.aspx) augmented by chaining service bus entities with auto-forwarding.

The idea is that each app has it's own queue local in it's resource group where it drops log messages. This local queue then forwards the log message to a central log queue. When the log message lands in the central queue, it triggers a worker service (or similar) to process the message appropriately (format and send it to appropriate data store)

The thinking behind this approach is that if the central message queue goes down, the log messages will be retained in the app's local queue, thus providing an additional layer of resiliency. And if the local queue fails, the app can log to some other data store as a back up\ redundancy.

So I am just wondering if there is any drawbacks or reasons why the above would not be a good approach or if anyone can recommend a better way to design/ implement a shared logging framework in Azure?

Answer (score 2):

It would be easy to implement a log client that for example puts log messages onto a Service Bus Queue. You would have a very well protected message queue with automatic poison letter detection etc. Big question of course is: will you need it, or would it suffice with something simpler like Storage Queues, or even logging directly to storage?

Any type of logging can, and should be done as a background task using a task-internal pub/sub pattern (as in for example, the [Event Aggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx)).

**Existing Log Frameworks**

There are also log frameworks that already have implemented much of what you're describing, one of the more popular ones, named [Log4Net](http://log4net.sourceforge.net/release/1.2.0.30316/doc/manual/introduction.html), uses the concept of an ***appender*** as its way of describing the engine that does the actual logging. This can really be anything; storage, queues, databases, and with very little effort, you can also write your own appenders to fit your need.

**A matter of cost**

More often than not, this comes down to cost more than resiliency. And resiliency is a matter of risk calculation. How likely is it that your system will break down and in that event, how likely is it that you're stuck with no logfiles to look at. And lastly, what do you need logged that is not already being handled by the existing logs that happen around your application's runtime? And last, what will it cost you to NOT have that information?
The answer to those questions will give you a number that you then can translate to investment in the proper logging framework.

I know that as developers, we always seek the perfect solution, but that's not always the logical choice.

Comment: Hi Pedro, thanks for the quick reply. I was thinking of using something like Log4Net or Serilog in a worker process monitoring the central queue to send  the actual formatted exception/message to the final data store (e.g database). In this way, only one service would need to know the details of logging and would contain all logging related code (and so all log specific code would be in a single system). All other apps would then only need to worry about sending a message to a local resource queue. I thought this would be a good way to separate concerns

Comment: Indeed. I've done a similar thing, where I use IEventAggregator (no longer maintained) as my in-memory pub/sub. The subscriber does nothing but post the log messages to a queue, in my case an Azure Storage Queue